# Can't delete WebSphere profile - what left to do?

Tags: websphere

My WebSphere profile has issues, so I wanted to delete and recreate it. When I do the following from a command line (win7)

```
[WAS-installDir]/bin/manageprofiles.sh -delete -profileName [Profilname]
```

it tells me that the profile is corrupted and can't be deleted:

[image]

So what other possibilites do I have? (The German reads to: The Profile ________ is currently in use. Repeat the command at a later point in time. If this is not possible, the profile might be corrupted. Use the command validateAndUpdateRegistry and recreate the profile.
INSTCONFFAILED: The profile cannot be deleted. More information can be found at C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere8.5\AppServer\logs\manageprofiles_________delete.log)

In the mentioned log file it says again that the profile can't be deleted because it is in use.

Is there a way to delete this profile anyhow, without destroying something important? Is it saved in some directory that I can simply delete?

Comment: Make certain you have no process running associated to that profile.  Also make sure you have no service(s) associated to that profile (see https://www.coderanch.com/t/445723/application-servers/Profile-deletion).  You can also use the console to remove everything associated to the profile (applications, servers, nodes, resources, ...).  Once that is done, then remove the profile.

Comment: As Nic3500 wrote - the most probable is that you have still java processes running associated with this profile. Kill all java processes and retry.

Comment: reboot the machine if you are unable to find and kill all the java related websphere processes and retry. I have done this in the past

Comment: @VasanthRaghavan Rebooting the machine doesn't help unfortunately (also was my first idea). I deinstalled WebSphere completely and reinstalled everything. Now I have to re-setup the whole system, so unfortunately I can't continue working on the error as posted.